# Couldn't update and download any package in bash for windows

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use official bash for windows 64bit (ubuntu 14.04). The problem is, when I am trying to update any package or install new packages (ex. g++, etc.) I always get the same error :

```
root@notebook:~# sudo apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
g++ is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up qemu-user-binfmt (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.41) ...
update-binfmts: warning: unable to close /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register: Invalid argument
update-binfmts: warning: unable to enable binary format qemu-aarch64
update-binfmts: exiting due to previous errors
dpkg: error processing package qemu-user-binfmt (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qemu-user-binfmt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Bad script of package qemu-user-binfmt. First you need try cmd: apt-get purge qemu-user-binfmt. If problem not solved you need remove files qemu-user-binfmt.pre*, qemu-user-binfmt.post* in dir /var/lib/dpkg/info/. And run apt-get remove qemu-user-binfmt.

Comment: @Šerg thank you. it helped. could you write your solution as answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad script of package qemu-user-binfmt.

First you need try cmd:

```
apt-get purge qemu-user-binfmt
```

If problem not solved you need remove files in dir /var/lib/dpkg/info/:

```
qemu-user-binfmt.pre*
qemu-user-binfmt.post*
```

And run

```
apt-get remove qemu-user-binfmt
```